# How to add Laravel CSRF Token in VueJS file?

Tags: html, laravel, vuejs2

I am creating a simple login form using Laravel and VueJS.

Since I am designing the template of Login Form in `.vue` file, `@csrf` doesn't work at all.

So, how can I add csrf-token (`@csrf`) or any of the blade syntax in any of the forms in .vue file?

Login.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="app">
        <form action="/login" method="post">
            @csrf  <!-- How can I make this work -->
            <input type="text" class="email">
            <input type="password" class="password">
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

So back in the day Laravel had this special part of the main `/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php` that exposed the CSRF token in all views as a javascript variable.

It looked something like this:

```
<script>
    window.CSRF_TOKEN = '{{ csrf_token() }}';
</script>
```

That way in your Vue, React, jQuery or vanilla Javascript you could just use the global variable `window.CSRF_TOKEN` and reference the Laravel CSRF token.

For those who don't know `window` is a special variable in Javacript, similar to the idea of super globals in PHP like `$_SERVER` or `$_GET`.